# CGDataProviderCopyData retaining data

Tags: ios, memory-management, core-graphics, core-foundation

Instruments is showing that I have a lot of persistent allocations created with CGDataProviderCopyData.

I am calling CGDataProviderCopyData then releasing the data reference with CFRelease afterwards. I'm using a UInt8 point to the data with CFDataGetBytePtr.

This code is done in an UIImaveView category

```
    CGImageRef imageRef = self.image.CGImage;

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef);
    CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(provider);
    const UInt8* data = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);

    // do stuff with data...

    CFRelease(pixelData);
```

I'm not sure why pixelData is being retained if I use CFRelease.

Answer (score 0):

You should release the provider:

```
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
```